# Unity crash to a blue screen after login

Tags: graphics

I recently updated to 12.10 quintal and to my surprise the desktop won't load. After logging in it brings up my wallpaper for a while then it turns to a plain blue screen. After all this I have to ctrl-alt-f1 and use terminal to get out. I know unity 2d is no longer supported and I'm not sure my graphics card can support the openGL that the desktop needs. It's a nividia GEforce FX 5200 128mb.

I've done research and nothing of my problem occurs.

I can switch to classic gnome but I would prefer unity but if that's not possible then idk.

Plz help!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Unity2D was discontinued, much to the dismay of many of us that still use some pretty ancient cards. So, for some people this means that Unity cannot be loaded.

Now, I understand that Unity has become a central part of Ubuntu (and I expect some backlash for my answer), however in your case I would recommend ditching it. It may be painful and not what you're used to, but it may be your only choice.

From a VT (Ctrl+Alt+F1), run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

or in newer versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

That should pull in everything that you need to use the classic Gnome interface from the pre-Unity days. You may even be brave and try gnome-shell, but I'm guessing you'll get nowhere with that either.

In order to use it, you have to select it at the login screen. To do this, before you enter your password click the Ubuntu logo just up and to the right of the password input box. From here you select "Gnome Classic" and upon login you should be in a fully-working desktop environment!

EDIT: As noted by strugee below, `gnome-session-fallback` will not work in future versions.  It has been renamed to `gnome-panel`.

Comment: This is not a permanent solution. `gnome-session-fallback` is already obsolete: key parts are broken and it has been completely removed from GNOME 3.8. As a result, this session will no longer be available when Saucy comes out. If you really want the classic session, use either MATE or Cinnamon.

Comment: O.O I didn't know that! I'm still using 12.04 of course. I could see why though, Gnome Classic was based off Gnome 2, and ported to Gnome 3 later but it's fallen by the wayside for sure with Gnome Shell. I wasn't aware the Cinnamon was even an option in stock Ubuntu -- and I've never heard of MATE.

Comment: While Cinnamon *is* available in the Ubuntu repositories, it's only available starting with Raring so is not applicable to his Ubuntu version. MATE doesn't appear to be available at all via official repositories, though I suppose a PPA may have it.

Comment: MATE and Cinnamon both are related to Linux Mint. Gnome Classic was thought by many people to be a supported classic environment, but it was actually just the shell that you'd be booted to if your graphics card didn't support GNOME 3 - hence the fallback part of `gnome-session-fallback`. It's broken because there isn't a big motivation to keep it working. MATE is a full fork of GNOME2. It doesn't have a PPA, IIRC, but it does have hosted APT repositories.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the fallback implication. Upon Ubuntu 12.04 beta release I had actually corrected the gnome-shell package maintainers. gnome-session-fallback was not a dependency of gnome-shell, causing my home-spun Gnome Shell default BootCD to fail in a VM. Personally, I think it's sad to see all these legacy GUI's dying. Linux, a system touted to work well on legacy hardware has been destroyed in the sense that legacy hardware can no longer support the GUI's being released in mainline distributions. I'd like to see a "no system left behind" mantra behind development, honestly.

Comment: I know, I never miss an opportunity to proclaim that Hardy was the greatest Ubuntu release of all time - it was the height of GNOME2 and it had the very best desktop background. That being said, there's always LXDE and Xfce. And, I've tried MATE, and I think it just needs time to mature before it becomes a very good choice. (Right now they have to port the system to GNOME3 technologies, e.g. mate-conf [fork of gconf] to GSettings.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8910/discussion-between-strugee-and-githlar)