# Could Unity 2D speed up 3D games on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, ati, games, unity-2d

I know that Ubuntu 12.04 allows for specifying Unity 2D or 3D at login.  Using Unity 2D when playing 3D games is supposed to make things work faster.  Does this also apply to Ubuntu 13.04?  If so, how can I get the Unity 2D desktop on my Raring Ringtail?

I am using an AMD 6670 graphics card with 1GB RAM and Catalyst 13.4 proprietary driver.  I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, running "Unity 2D" will make games faster. However, there is no longer Unity 2D. You can use other desktop environments. XFCE is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Using XFCE or LXDE should suffice, but judging by your specs, you probably wont be able to play very graphically intense games.

Answer (score 0):

In 13.04 there is no Unity2D. However [gnome-session-fallback](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-session-fallback) [image: Install gnome-session-fallback] is still supported. After installing we can select the desktop environment on log in:

[image]

After we selected GNOME fallback (no effects) a GNOME classic desktop will be loaded without Unity, and without Compiz running. This will leave more resources available for games, and there will also be no interference of Unity key bindings when running full screen applications.

Comment: gnome-session-fallback is not a permanent solution. See my comment in http://askubuntu.com/a/299323/49090

Comment: The question is about 13.04. Game performance issues in Saucy may be different.

Comment: So? When he eventually upgrades, he'll have to move DEs. It's a solution, just not a permanent one